# Why does javascript assume that a function is a variable?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Well, I just noticed that JS somehow takes a function as a variable in my code. Here is it:

```
<template>
  <div id="">
      <div>
          <input type="text" v-model="value">
          <button v-on:click='[factorial(), show=!show]'>Factorial</button>
          <span v-show="show">{{value}}</span>
      </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return {
        value : 0,
        show: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
  },
  computed: {
        factorial(x=this.value){
            if (!x){return 1}
            else {return x*factorial(x-1)}
        }
  },
  mounted() {}
}
</script>
<style lang="scss">
</style>
```

The error is ReferenceError: Can't find variable: factorial.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot pass arguments to `computed` properties, that is what `methods` are for.

You also need to use `this` when calling the function.

```js
methods: {
    factorial(x) {
        if (!x) {
            x = this.value;
        }

        return x * this.factorial(x-1);
    },
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You mustn't use `factorial()` as a computed function. You should instead make it a method:

```js
<template>
  <div id="">
      <div>
          <input type="text" v-model="value">
          <button v-on:click='[factorial(), show=!show]'>Factorial</button>
          <span v-show="show">{{value}}</span>
      </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return {
        value : 0,
        show: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    factorial(x=this.value){
        if (!x){return 1}
        else {return x * this.factorial(x-1)}
    } 
  },
}
</script>
```

Here is a working sandbox for you:

https://codesandbox.io/s/lingering-voice-p6d9l

Comment: Thank you! I am going to try that